# Blocking Adsense clicks on my computers

Tags: google-adsense, localhost

As a webmaster what I need is that I should be able to see the Adsense ads on my sites but if I click by mistake then it should not make a real click just to abide by Google Adsense policies.

This method can be replicated on other computers as well so that my employees too don't click them but at the same time be able to make decision about the ads and their positions.

I guess I need to add some domains/subdomains(eg `pagead2.googlesyndication.com`) in the hosts file so that clicks on Adsense ads and also Adsense search ads be blocked.

I need some standard way to do it on my laptop running Windows.

I already know what @Harpreet has suggested. I don't want any test environment. And I'm not asking for Ad testing tool and strategy.

I can't tell my naive employees that they should not click the ads. Otherwise if I tell them to not click real ads while posting content, then anybody can harm me by inordinate clicking the ads later. In short the Google Adsense policy must be kept confidential and not told to anybody else who does not need it.

Comment: Your edits make this unclear (and shouldn't contain editorial comments to other answers). We get this question quite often and the answer has always been to use Google's [Publisher Toolbar](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348743?hl=en) for this: `which allows you to view the ads that may show on any webpage and click them without worrying about invalid clicks being generated on your account.` If you don't want an "Ad testing tool and strategy", then what are you specifically asking for?

Comment: @dan i want a setup in which everyone in my office will work on my sites but any clicks on ads should not be recorded. Nor do  I want to disclose them that clicking is forbidden.

Comment: What you're describing is a network filter, which some routers have built-in. That can also be accomplished by editing the hosts file on every computer like you wrote. The downside of both is that _every_ Google ad would be blocked so users in your office wouldn't be able to see any of them (including some SERP results at the top of Google). You appear to know how to do the later, but how to setup a network filter is really outside the scope of this site. You might ask that over at Super User since they cover routers and hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Self-clicking is against Google Adsense Policy. Google doesn't tolerate any spamming activity like these. but if you made click by mistake once then are enough chances that Google will not close your account. But if you are doing it again and again then it will.

But any user can click on your ad. for that there is no action against you. but for this, you have to need to use the site as a user, logged out. but too many clicks can affect your Adsense Account.

But if you want that to keep your account safe from the self-clicking activity then use Google Publisher Toolbar in your Chrome.

Comment: I did not ask this

Comment: I Tell you everything and I understand what you said. you can use  Google Publisher Toolbar as I mentioned above to avoid self-clicking.  no need to make changes in Adsense Files it will be Negative effect. Google Protect your ads when you use GPT

Answer (score 0):

Google's adsense policies show that you shouldn't be positioning your ads in such a way that it creates accidental clicks. I know that you probably didn't set your ads up in that way but it's worth mentioning since you're worried that you and colleagues might click ads by mistake.

If you're really worried about clicking the ads by accident, you always could just run one of those famous chrome extensions that block ads.

You also could run a PHP script that detects the client's IP, or logged in username and if the IP/username is yours it doesn't display the script for the ad.